# Cannot locate view in Django MVC

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to get started on a simple project to display a bit of HTML. However when I run my code I cannot seem to locate the html file. I am following what the tutorial on the Django website says

"Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create a file called index.html. In other words, your template should be at polls/templates/polls/index.html. Because of how the app_directories template loader works as described above, you can refer to this template within Django simply as polls/index.html."

SO I put my index.html into

```
    homepage/templates/homepage/index.html
```

I have not yet added anything to my models.py

proj urls.py:

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'homepage/',include('homepage.urls', namespace = "homepage")),
    )
```

app urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
    from homepage import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    )
```

views.py:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import RequestContext, loader

    def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template('homepage/index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template)
    )
```

*********UPDATE*************************

So with a bit of tinkering I seem to be able to grab the HTML file. However, the display of this HTML file is not behaving correctly. For instance, if I were to have this bit:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The output would be a blank page. The page source would display:

```
    <Text Node: '<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <b'>
```

Not sure why it is behaving this way. Would it have to do withi my having django-pipeline installed and also twitter bootstrap?

Comment: What is your ```TEMPLATE_LOADERS``` setting?

Comment: @kroolik
omg..totally forgot about editing those...Sorry I've been up for a long time now. Post a solution! Ill gladly accept it as an answer!

Comment: @kroolik Actually my TEMPLATE_LOADERS are set default to TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
My page runs now however it is not printing the correct output =[

Comment: Instead of returning ```HttpResponse``` with contents being the template object (with it's nodes), try ```render``` or ```render_to_response``` from [django.http.shortcuts](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/). Template's string representation __is not__ the rendered contents (this is accomplished by ```.render()``` method).

Comment: @kroolik Thanks! This worked! What I did --> http://pastebin.com/UKWxw2Bd

However, I did not understand what you meant by "Template's string representation is not the rendered contents (this is accomplished by .render() method)" If you don't mind, could you explain this to me in layman's terms. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `return HttpResponse(template)`. The `HttpResponse` accepts `content` for it's first argument. The content could be anything that has a string representation (implements either `__str__` or `__unicode__`, depending on passing `Content-Encoding` header to the response and it's charset) or is iterable. In the latter case, all elements yield by it have to representable by a string.

The issue you are experiencing is that you are passing a `Template` object to the response, which is **iterable** (implements `__iter__` method). Iterating the template yields all the compiled nodes. The nodes themselves implement `__repr__` which is used when `__str__` is missing. And the `HttpResponse`, if `content` is iterable, returns all elements that are yield from iterating the iterable.

You can simulate this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('homepage/index.html')
    for n in template:
        print n
    return HttpResponse(template)
```